# Problem in understanding Interface and FormGroup issue in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

My question may be duplicate, apologize for that. there is lot of solutions available same issue in SO, but unfortunately am not able to understand that in technical terms.

**Problem 1**

```
src/app/models/dataModel.ts:2:5
2     id: number;
      ~~
The expected type comes from property 'id' which is declared here on type 'DataModel'


Error: src/app/models/dataModel.ts:2:5 - error TS2564: Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

2     id: number;
```

my **dataModal.ts**

```
export class DataModel {
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    gender?: string;
    age?: number;
    address?: string;
    city?: string;
    country?: string;
    status?: string;
    date?: Date;
}
```

**case-details.component.ts**

```
export class CasesDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoadingResult = true;
  cases: DataModel = { id: null || undefined, name: '', gender: '', age: null || undefined, address: '', city: '' };
```

.
for problem 1, whenever I **?** optional operator, problem gone and app running smoothly.. I would like to understand, what is the purpose of using **?** and why?

**Problem 2**

```
Error: src/app/component/add-case/add-case.component.ts:22:3 - error TS2564: Property 'formGroup' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

22   formGroup: FormGroup;
     ~~~~~~~~~
```

trying to add form data, so initializing like below in `add-case.component.ts`

```
export class AddCaseComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoadingResult = true;

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  id = null;
  name = '';
  age = null;
  status = '';
  gender = '';
  genderList = ['Male', 'Female',];
  statusList = [ 'Positive', 'Negative'];
  address = '';
  city = '';
  country = '';


  constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      age: [null, Validators.required],
      status: [null, Validators.required],
      gender: [null, Validators.required],
      address: [null, Validators.required],
      city: [null, Validators.required],
      country: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }



saveRecord(): void {
    this.isLoadingResult = true;
    this.api.addNewCaseDetails(this.formGroup.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
// other stuffs
}

}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.8",
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

Could someone pls help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are defining class but without inializing properties (either in constructor or directly when you define them). Since Typescript is showing you this message, I assume that you are in strict mode which is why you get this.

To answer your first question : the ? in `id?:` means that the property is optional, it is not necessaries for her to have a value, it can be null. Another solution would be to define a constructor with the id parameter :
`constructor(id: number){this.id = id;}`

For your second question, you should try moving your form initialization in your constructor body :

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      age: [null, Validators.required],
      status: [null, Validators.required],
      gender: [null, Validators.required],
      address: [null, Validators.required],
      city: [null, Validators.required],
      country: [null, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

as for the why it is a best practice I don't have the answer at the moment but i'll look for it.

Edit : I looked a bit and found this : [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization).

Typescript need to be sure that a property not defined as optional has a value (to avoid 'undefined' and technical issues at runtime). It seems that instead of moving your formGroup initialization to your constructor, you can also declare it like this :

```js
myFormGroup!: FormGroup  // see the ! mark, it means that the property will be initialized in an other place that the constructor.

constructor(...) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.myFormGroup = this.fb.formGroup({...});
}
```

Comment: solution for 2nd problems is interesting, that solved my issue. ok.. tell me what if my id mandatory when im using json-server and db.json has id : 1 instead of id: 'someRondomID9090'

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question here :/

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it clearly... @mJehanno  Actually, trying to ask like what should do if my id is mandatory and its type is always number

Comment: well, you have multiple solutions here, the first and probably the best is to make an interface instead of class. In typescript interface are made to define the shape of some data, where a class is more intelligent (having methods ...). So if you don't need any method on your  DataModel, then consider make it an interface. Another solution would be to add a constructor to your class with a parameter and whenever you have to create a dataModal you call it : `new DataModal(200) // where 200 would be your Id`

Answer (score 0):

For Problem 1 I do not have I direct answer.

For Problem 2 I would try to set the from outside of the `ngOnInit()` function.

```
export class AddCaseComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoadingResult = true;

  id = null;
  name = '';
  age = null;
  status = '';
  gender = '';
  genderList = ['Male', 'Female', 'Transgender'];
  statusList = ['Recoverd', 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Under treatment', 'Dead'];
  address = '';
  city = '';
  country = '';
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      age: [null, Validators.required],
      status: [null, Validators.required],
      gender: [null, Validators.required],
      address: [null, Validators.required],
      city: [null, Validators.required],
      country: [null, Validators.required]
      }};

  constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private 
              formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Learner, can you add some getter and setter to change the value of the class ? Too, i suggest you to work with interface to have a model and working on it